# Extract PID from top in UNIX

Tags: linux, string, unix, system, pid

I would like to extract PID from top for desired process and user. So, I can get a consistently updating list with this command `top -u meh`, but how do I extract PIDs for java for user meh from here and get the result below?

```
$top -u meh 

34249 meh     20   0   36.7g  11.7g   2240 S  97.0  1.5   2594:00 java
36864 meh     20   0   37.7g  12.2g   2232 S  97.0  1.6   2588:58 java
33607 meh     20   0   37.9g  12.2g   2244 S  96.7  1.6   2584:22 java
17027 meh     20   0  163228   3420   1596 R   1.0  0.0   0:00.10 top
  617 meh     20   0  117872    316    312 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 bash
 1626 meh     20   0  117872    236    236 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 bash
 2056 meh     20   0  130624    276    276 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 screen
 2057 meh     20   0  117892    312    308 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 bash
 3912 meh     20   0  117892    248    248 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 bash
 4516 meh     20   0  117872    236    236 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 bash
 7166 meh     20   0  117872    312    308 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 bash
```

result:

```
34249 36864 33607
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the baseline for it, you can add more grep and pipe if you want specific user

```
top -p $(ps -fea|grep -i java |grep -v grep|cut -d' ' -f3 | tr '\n' ','|  head --bytes -1 )
```

Comment: `grep -i '[j]ava'` eliminates the need to anti-grep for grep `grep -v grep` so eliminates one process from the pipeline. Not that that's going to make much difference, but eh. — and/or use `grep -F` / `fgrep` since there's no actual regex being used.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -aux | grep 'meh' | grep 'java' | awk '{print $2}'
```

first print all processes by using `ps`
first `grep` list all processes by meh,
second `grep` lists only the ones that contain java (within the previous set)
then it prints the second column with `awk`

EDIT:
if you do not want to match other processes that CONTAIN `java` keyword in it you can tell ps which program you're looking for:

```
ps -C java -o user,pid | grep 'meh' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Actually, it is extracting non-java PIDs too. Didn't work.

Comment: you mean it's also extracting utilities running ON java but you want to list `java` main processes only? edited my answer to give you more strict example